# Accessing Textbox from GridView data cell (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
      protected void GridView2_OnCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Reply")
            {
                con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=myconnectionstring; Integrated Security = true; Connect Timeout = 30; User Instance = True";
                con.Open();

                string div = "','";
                GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView2.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SellerResponse VALUES ('" +
                    //THIS LINE IS THE ISSUE
                Request.QueryString["ID"] + div + selectedRow.Cells[2].Text + div + DateTime.Now.ToString() + div + selectedRow.Cells[3].Text + ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)(FindControl(selectedRow.Cells[1].UniqueID))).Text /*this is the cell that contains the textbox*/+ "');", con);
            }
        }
```

Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: You've got so much stuff crammed into one line of code you will never debug it.  And even if you got it to work, it would be unmaintainable.   Break each logical step out into a separate line of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                if (e.CommandName == "Reply")
                {

                   on = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
                   con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=myconnectionstring; Integrated Security = true; Connect Timeout = 30; User Instance = True";
                   con.Open();

                   string div = "','";
                   GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView2.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SellerResponse VALUES ('" +
                   //THIS LINE IS THE ISSUE
                   Request.QueryString["ID"] + div + GridView2.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text + div + DateTime.Now.ToString() + div + GridView2.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text + ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)(GridView2.Rows[index]Cells[1].FindControl("the name of the text box")).Text /*this is the cell that contains the textbox*/+ "');", con);

                }
            }


            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                string message = ee.Message;
            }
        }
```

Note:1- in aspx :`CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>'`

```
   2- use RowCommand event for the grid view.
```